# Authenticating user entered User-Name and Password, in an Ionic 2 App's login screen, with Azure Active Directory using ADAL Library

Tags: ionic2, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am developing an Ionic 2 App that is authenticating users against Microsoft Azure Active Directory. Having trouble in figuring out how to implement the following flow using ADAL:

User enters "user-name" and "password" **==>** Clicks on **Login** button **==>** App makes Azure AD call by passing over the user entered "user-name" and "password" **==>** Azure AD authenticates the user and returns back the result.

Following the Azure AD documentation, I was able to successfully implement "**server-flow**" where on making an Azure AD call, it opens up a new Microsoft Azure-AD login page for my app to enter "user-name" and "password". And upon successful authentication the user is landed back on to my app's home-page. This works fine but the experience is not great from UX perspective.

Following is the way I did it:

```
myAzure = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(MY_AZURE_APP_SERVICE_URL);
myAzure .login('aad').then(
        (result) => {
            //Successful Login
        }, 
        (err) {
            console.log("In client.login callback failed");
        });
});
```

Then, I followed Azure AD documentation to implement "**client-flow**". I have a question in this:

**1.** How do I pass in the "user-name" and "password" to Azure AD when I make "authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync()" call or "authContext.acquireTokenAsync()" call.

Upon going through the implementation of these methods in the ADAL library, it appears that

- "**authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync()**" can accept only **user-name** and not the **password**. So, is it safe to assume that this method is not supposed to be used for login purposes?
- "**authContext.acquireTokenAsync()**" can accept **user-name** but in addition, there is a parameter called "**extraQueryParameters**". Am I supposed to use this parameter to pass in the **password**? However, this is supposed to open-up a login page for the user on the screen. It did open a new login page on my device. So not sure how to develop my functionality.

If both of the above ways are not the right way to implement my flow of authentication then can somebody please help me by giving some pointers, links or sample links on how I can implement this?

My app's users are going to be in our corporate Azure-AD. I have created a separate Azure-AD Tenant for my app (also created the required setup so that it's tied up with my Azure App Service, etc.) and I would add users to this tenant when required.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have any problem about this issue? Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the **Client-managed authentication** flow enables you to provide a single sign-on experience for users or to retrieve additional user data from the identity provider.

That's mean if you doesn't authenticate the identity data provider before mobile authentication, it still require to prompt the users to enter their username and password.

> "authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync()" can accept only user-name and not the password. So, is it safe to assume that this method is not supposed to be used for login purposes?

This method is designed for get the token silently via getting the token from cache or renew the token using the refresh token. It is not designed for this purpose.

> "authContext.acquireTokenAsync()" can accept user-name but in addition, there is a parameter called "extraQueryParameters". Am I supposed to use this parameter to pass in the password? However, this is supposed to open-up a login page for the user on the screen. It did open a new login page on my device. So not sure how to develop my functionality.

No. You are not able to pass the password using this function. It will prompt users to enter their username and password by default. However if you have sign-in the Azure AD, you can acquire the access token without prompt via specify the `PromptBehavior.Never` like below:

```
var resoult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId,new Uri("http://localhost"),new PlatformParameters( PromptBehavior.Never)).Result;
Console.WriteLine(resoult.AccessToken);
```